# jQuery UI tab add event keeping same value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following simple code:

```
var tabs = null;
function addTab(id, title, data) {
    alert("Begin: " + data.name);
    if (tabs === null) {
        tabs = $("#center-tabs").tabs({
            tabTemplate: "<li style='line-height: 0.5'><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
            add: function (event, ui) {
                alert("Event: " + data.name);
            }
        });
    }
    tabs.tabs("add", id, title);
    tabs.tabs("select", id);
}
```

When I call:
    addTab("#tab-1", "Tab-1", {
        name: "Example 1"
    });
two alerts are displayed ("Begin: Example-1" and "Event: Example-1")

But if I call again:
    addTab("#tab-2", "Tab-2", {
        name: "Example-2"
    });
two alerts are displayed but first one with correct message and second with the message of the first call ("Begin: Example-2" but "Event: Example-1")

What I'm doing wrong?
Is it a tabs implementation bug?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a bug.

First time you call `addTab()` variable `tabs` is `null` so the body of if-statement is executed. Inside the if you define `add` method with a body works with `data.name` (`Example 1`). This is expected.

The problem is that during the 1st run a closure is created that contains the `data` variable with `Example 1` value. When you call your `addTab()` 2nd time `tabs` is already created and inside the `add` method `data.name` is still referring to the **old** `data.name` which got saved during the 1st run. Your `alert()` cannot see the new value of the `data`.

See http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ .

You can solve it by *not* accessing `addTabs` variables/parameters inside `add` directly because that will "save them" into a closure, but using other mechanism such as jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

```
var tabs = null;
function addTab(id, title, data) {
    if (tabs === null) {
        tabs = $("#center-tabs").tabs({
            tabTemplate: "...",
            add: function (event, ui) {
              console.log("Event: " + $(this).data('name'));
            }
        });
    }
    tabs.data('name', data.name);
    tabs.tabs("add", id, title);
    tabs.tabs("select", id);
}
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/azamax/edit#javascript,live)** is an example.

Comment: Thanks in makes sense and in fact at some point I though about it but I don't know why I discarded the closure situation... maybe I'm too tired :0)

Comment: @MichelFornaris Glad to help :). Please don't forget to upvote useful answers and accept one (see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)). Thank you :)!

Comment: @MichelFornaris Sorry, I forgot about the voting restrictions. Thank you :-) !

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up the tabs container on #center-tabs twice, once with each call to addTab.  Try changing your code like this:

```
var tabs = $("#center-tabs");
function addTab(id, title, data) {
    alert("Begin: " + data.name);
    if (!tabs.hasClass('ui-tabs')) {
        tabs.tabs({
            tabTemplate: "<li style='line-height: 0.5'><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
            add: function (event, ui) {
                alert("Event: " + data.name);
            }
        });
    }
    tabs.tabs("add", id, title);
    tabs.tabs("select", id);
}
```